# How to convert a json type input of a restlet request to a POJO?

Tags: java, json, jackson, restlet

I would like to write a simple method that receives a json that represents a POJO and just use that POJO.

Example (receiving and returning a POJO):

```
@Put("json")
public Representation b(JacksonRepresentation<Device> deviceRepresentation)
        throws IOException {
    Device device = deviceRepresentation.getObject();
    // Use the device
    return new JacksonRepresentation<Device>(device);
}
```

The above example throws an exception: *Conflicting setter definitions for property "locationRef"...*

Another option would have been using a JsonRepresentation, but I couldn't find a way to convert it to a POJO:

```
@Put("json")
public Representation b(JsonRepresentation jsonRepresentation) {
    // How to convert the jsonRepresentation to a POJO???
    return new JsonRepresentation(new Device("2", 2));
}
```

Jackson sounds a better tool for the job, as it has generic, thus mech more type safe - if only it would work...

Comment: This smacks of mixing an externalized form with compile-time logic.  My knee-jerk reaction is convert JSON to a Map, then convert that Map to a POJO via a util, then pass that POJO into your simple method.   Get rid of all this annotation stuff.   JSON != Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ne need to use any representation object. The following worked beautifully, using **jackson** in the background:

```
@Put
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Device b(Device device) {
    // Do something with the POJO!!!
    return device;
}
```

It converts the input and converts the output. Here's a curl example of how it works:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"port":3,"ip":"3"}' http://localhost:8888/restlet/
```

Result:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sun, 13 Oct 2013 02:03:48 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Development/1.0
Vary: Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 19

{"ip":"3","port":3}
```

Comment: Could you post up the resource code that uses this?  It's something I'd like to do but I'm trying to get my head around how it's wired up.  Doe sit just have a b(Device device) method?

Comment: Sure: public class Device {
 private String ip;
 private int port;

 @Deprecated
 public Device() {}
 
 public Device(String ip, int port) {
  super();
  this.ip = ip;
  this.port = port;
 }

 public String getIp() {
  return ip;
 }
 
 public int getPort() {
  return port;
 }
}

Comment: It seems that I could have dropped `@Produces` and `@Consumes` annotations. It is be parsed automatically. See the following for an example of how to do it: http://restlet.org/learn/guide/2.1/introduction/first-steps/first-application. curl would get the same results.